# Is Robocopy slow?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup

I'm using Robocopy in my Windows 10 PC, to back up to an external 3.5" hard drive mounted on a docking station (SATA to USB) on a USB 3.0 port.

I suspect it is slow compared to just a drag-and-drop with File Explorer or using a back-up software such as Macrium.  I haven’t tested this, I’m backing up now for the first time like this, I may be wrong.  It's been 5 hours to back up 250GB!.

Is Robocopy inherently slow? Perhaps because it’s very thorough in regards to integrity?

I’m thinking Robocopy may be more suited to other type of backups.
Any opinions much appreciated.

This is the command I'm using:
Robocopy F:\ D:\ /MIR  /R:0 /MT:32 /NP /B /SL /SJ /NFL /NDL /LOG:"C:\Users\JohnK\Documents\Backup.log"

Comment: What options are you using? What is your robocopy command? From experience the `/zb` (restartable) option can make it painfully slow. Other than that I have gotten essentially native disk speeds.

Comment: Also what kind of usb port is your external drive connected to? USB2 is 480Mbps which equates to around 30-40 Megabytes per second after overheads. A USB 3 port (usually blue) would be faster. Does your external drive support USB 3?

Comment: But no, robocopy is typically not "slow", not any slower than using the built in Windows copy tool anyway, and can be optimised through various options.

Comment: I've added the command I'm using and the docking station is plugged to a blue USB 3.0 port.  Thanks!

Comment: `/mt:32` seems overkill and on spinning rust disks might end up with the head thrashing the disk. Try lowering it to 2 or 4? I've never used `/b` and dont see why that would cause a problem but the rest of your options look okay. I used robocopy to transfer one machine to another last week and it managed to keep a gigabit ethernet connection pretty well saturated at around 100MB/s

Comment: Thanks Mokubai,  I'll try removing those and redo the backup.

Comment: What are you copying? Many small files perhaps? Or some big files? What make and model are the drives involved? Are you using a third-party anti-virus scanner?

Comment: Hi Daniel: I'm moving data from same make&model drives (internal & externally attached): WD Blue 3TB Desktop Hard Disk Drive - 5400 RPM SATA 6 Gb/s 64MB Cache 3.5 Inch.

...sometimes I'll copy from the internal 2.5" system SSD.  No antivirus (just Windows'), data is family videos, photos and documents

Comment: I found the source 2TB HDD had bad sectors and I File explorer got stuck while copying a couple of video files, may be that was the issue.  Removing /B and /MT seemed to help though.  I'll keep testing this.